# Im building a JS SDK client for my custom Aragon OSx plugin and struggling to pass in data

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create a custom sdk client for my Aragon OSx governance plugin.

I have run into the issue where I wanna upload the metadata of the proposals to IPFS, but Aragons IPFS SDK doesnt not seem compatible with nodejs (File type missing from global namespace I think).

I looked at the source code on github and tried to make the same `https` request to the server using `axios`, but I all `Content-Type headers` I try get me a `415` with "unsupported content type". Removing the header gives me a "missing content-type header" so this is also not the solution.

Could anyone tell me what `Content-Type` I should use? I have tried `application/octet-stream`, `application/json`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `text/plain`. I couldn't find anywhere what content type the fetch package attaches in this case to your call.

This is the code:

```js
    const config = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://ipfs-0.aragon.network/api/v0/add",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain", // what should this be??
        "X-API-KEY": "b477RhECf8s8sdM7XrkLBs2wHc4kCMwpbcFC55Kt"
      },
      params: {
        "path": json
      },
    };
    
    const res = await axios(config);
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a form data like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const metadata = {
  name: "This is a dao"
  // other props
}
let data = new FormData();
data.append('path', metadata);

let config = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://ipfs-0.aragon.network/api/v0/add',
  headers: { 
    'X-API-KEY': 'b477RhECf8s8sdM7XrkLBs2wHc4kCMwpbcFC55Kt', 
  },
  data : data
};

const res = await axios(config)
```